# Swipe effect for uiimageviews

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I have a little question. I've made a little image gallery with a swipe effect to skip through the uiimageviews. That works fine but I want to improve it. The next or previous picture is shown not until the swipe has finished. But I want it to behave like the photo library for example or the home screen, that the imageview 'follows' the touch and skips to the next or previous picture when a certain point is reached.
I hope I've made myself clear :-)
It's just that I want to simulate the swipe effect of the photo library.

Comment: Try the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504393/how-do-you-implement-swipe-able-image-stacks-like-the-photo-app-using-the-iphone).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest by far is to use an `UIScrollView` and to enable *paging* like that:

```
 myScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
```

See [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006922-CH3-SW13) for details.

Comment: I somehow don't get along with the UIScrollView and paging. I looked at the apple pagecontrol sample code and scrollingmadness code but I didn't get it. All I want is 3 uiimageviews scrolling in a loop. But it seems that you need a hell lot of code to do this. 
Ok lets go deeper into this. ScrollingMadness seems to be what I was looking for.

Comment: If ou want to loop them you'll have to do some code. This is not a trivial usage -- at least in terms of the current state of the sdk. Maybe you should think about doing a completely custom implementation, but this has several hicups...